# Monitor all emails received in Exchange, including those that bounce

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange, exchange-2010

How can I monitor my Exchange 2010 server to see all emails that come in regardless of whether there is a recipient in the system or not? I just imported a lot of distribution groups from CSV and I am nervous/curious to see if everything went smoothly, so I would like to know when mails that come to us bounce.

Answer (score 3):

The built-in Message Tracking functionality will show you all messages that have been received by your SMTP servers and will give you details about how they were handled. You won't see the content of the messages but it sounds like you're just interested in details about delivery.

Comment: Thanks - is there a PowerShell cmdlet available to report on stuff from the Message Tracking utility so that you could find all bounced messages?

Comment: Or alternatively, could I set up a "catch all" email box so nothing bounces?

Comment: I always found it a good idea to enable [SMTP logging](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124531.aspx) as I am used to reading postfix logs. [You also could enable catchall](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691132(EXCHG.80).aspx), but it would become a spam honeypot quickly. You can use powershell's [Get-MessageTrackingLog](http://www.simple-talk.com/content/print.aspx?article=681) and parse through the log.